# How to run same function when taking user inputs

Tags: c++, visual-c++, while-loop

I wanted to make a basic game-similar console program...so the thing is, how can I make the same function run again when user input is N/n without any errors....this is my code . When I enter N/n it becomes as in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epEeF.png)...Im using Visual Studio C++ 2015 . Thank you in advance

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

string name;
int age;
char prompt;

void biodata()
{
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Name : ";  getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Age : "; cin >> age;
}

void showBio()
{
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Thank you for providing your data...";
    cout << "\nPlease confirm your data...(Y/N)\n" << endl;

    //printing border
    cout << setfill('-') << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << endl;
    //printing student record
    cout << setfill(' ') << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << "Name" << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << "Age" << setw(1) << "|" << endl;
    //printing border
    cout << setfill('-') << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << endl;
    //printing student record
    cout << setfill(' ') << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << name << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << age << setw(1) << "|" << endl;
    //printing border
    cout << setfill('-') << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << endl;
    //printing student record

    cin >> prompt;

}

int main()
{
    cout << "Hi User, my name is Cheary. I'm your Computated Guidance (CG), nice to meet you..." << endl;
    cout << "Please provide your data..." << endl;
    biodata();
    showBio();

    if (prompt == 'Y' || 'y')
    {
        cout << "Thank you for giving cooperation...\nWe will now proceed to the academy..." << endl;
    }

    while (prompt == 'N' || 'n')
    {
        cout << "Please re-enter your biodata..." << endl;
        biodata();
        showBio();
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't use global variables**! Pass them as parameters or return values.
`using namespace std;` is bad practice. Better using full qualified names.

The problem you see is because when you previouly executed `cin >> something;`, the '\n' of Enter key is still there when it comes to `getline(std::cin, name);`. You then get right away an empty name.

**`cin.clear()` does not do what you think**, see [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear).

To prevent this, you can ue `std::ws`:

```
getline(cin >> std::ws, name);
```

These two conditions are wrong, and always true:

```
if (prompt == 'Y' || 'y') // equivalent to (prompt == 'Y' || 'y' not null) 
while (prompt == 'N' || 'n') // same with 'n' not null
```

You have to write `prompt` twice:

```
if (prompt == 'Y' || prompt == 'y')
while (prompt == 'N' || prompt == 'n')
```

Use [std::cin.ignore()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) instead of `std::system("pause");` which is not portable.